# I am getting a default value of 0 when I attempt to insert value in array after the I sorted

Tags: java

I have an integer array of size 4. I am adding elements to it via the add method. This is as an unsorted array. I am sorting it via the sort method shown in the code below. The sort method places the smallest number in the position a[0]. When I try to add elements after I call the sort method I always get a return value of 0. Is there a way around this?

```
  import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Scrap {
    private static int[] array = new int[4];
    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scrap pq = new Scrap();
        pq.add(4);
        pq.insert(3);
        pq.add(5);

        pq.sort();// smallest to largest sort method.
        // System.out.println(array[0]);
        pq.insert(1);
        pq.sort();
        int test = pq.Minimum();
        System.out.println("The smallest element of the array is " + test);
        pq.sort();
    }

    //
    public void add(int input) {
        insert(input);
    }

    // Method to insert number into the array.
    public void insert(int input) {
        array[i] = input;
        i++;
    }

    // Finding smallest number of the array.
    public int Minimum() {
        int a = array[0];
        return a;
    }

    // Sorts the array from smallest to largest integer
    public void sort() {
        int first, temp;
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            first = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[first])
                    first = j;
            }
            temp = array[first];
            array[first] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }

    }

    public int remove() {
        return delete();
    }

    public int delete() {
        return remove();
    }
    // Method to convert the array into a string for output
}
```

Comment: And why do you think it should be anything other than zero?

Comment: I am not sure that's why I am here.  I inserted a 1 into the array using the insert method not sure what I did wrong

Comment: Your sort method is incorrect. `j = 1; j <= 1`? And `i = array.length - 1`. It's "off by one", a few times...

Comment: I'd rather start by cleaning up the code. E.g. why do you have add AND insert or delete AND remove? The Minimum method is broken as well...

Comment: @home I have both add AND insert methods because I was asked to write it like that. My professor wanted us to us insert as a call to add and remove as a call to deletemin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in a nutshell:

- You start with an array of length 4.

  - At this point the array contains 4 zeros, that is: `[0, 0, 0, 0]`
- You add 4, 3, and 5. These operations update the content of the array to `[4, 3, 5, 0]`.
- You sort the array. This should change the content of the array to `[0, 3, 4, 5]`. In fact it changes to `[0, 5, 3, 4]`, which means your implementation of `sort` is clearly broken.

  - You probably didn't expect the 0 value to move. **You can fix this by sorting only the first 3 values.** (And, of course, you should also fix your implementation of `sort`.)
- Then when you insert 1, the program updates the value at index 3, so the content changes to `[0, 5, 3, 1]`.

If you implement the fix I suggested above, and sort only the first `size` elements, then the content after the first call to `sort` should become `[3, 4, 5, 0]`, and the content after the insert 1 should become `[3, 4, 5, 1]`. And when you sort that again, the content should become `[1, 3, 4, 5]` and the smallest value will be 1 as expected, instead of 0.

More concretely:

- First of all, change `private static int i = 0;` to `private int size = 0;`. The name `i` is extremely inappropriate here, and will surely confuse you. `size` is appropriate. It also doesn't make sense to make it `static`, so I suggest to drop that keyword.
- Fix the implementation of `sort`. There are many basic sorting algorithms that are easy to implement. In the implementation, instead of going until `array.size`, go until `size`. Do you see the difference? `size` is the field in `Scrap`, essentially it's the number of elements you added using the `add` or `insert` methods.

Some cleaning up would be good too:

- Delete the `add` method and rename `insert` to `add`.
- Delete the `remove` and `delete` methods. They are not used, and you will get a stack overflow if you try to use them as they are now (the methods call each other, forever)

---

Look at the content of the array after each step in the program.

After `Scrap pq` is created, this is the content of its array:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then a couple of modifications:

> ```
> pq.add(4);
> pq.insert(3);
> pq.add(5);
> ```

The content at this point:

```
[4, 3, 5, 0]
```

So far so good.

Then you sort it:

> ```
> pq.sort();
> ```

The content at this point:

```
[0, 5, 3, 4]
```

Ouch. The sort implementation doesn't work very well, does it. But let's ignore that for now. Next step:

> ```
> pq.insert(1);
> ```

The content at this point:

```
[0, 5, 3, 1]
```

None of this behavior makes sense, probably this is not how you intended the program to work. Review the program, verify the content after each step. Do not proceed to the next step until the current step is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you will be using a correct `sort` method (because, this is not correct, you can use Arrays.sort). But still with a correct sort, there is a logical problem in your code.

At the beginning, the array contains all 0s. After adding the first 3 int, when you call the sort method, the array contains the values in following order:

```
0,3,4,5
```

Note that, the value of `i` is not changed. At this state the value of i is 3. So when you insert 1, the new values become

```
0,3,4,1
```

So after sorting again, the values of arrays become

```
0,1,3,4
```

So obviously the minimum will retrun 0

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is the most effective way to sort an array. It is possible to do this with just 1 for loop. Try this to sort your array from smallest to largest.

```
int temp;
for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
    temp=array[i];
    array[i]=array[i+1];
    array[i+1]=temp;
    i=-1;
}
    }
```

Comment: This is actually pretty clever. I didn't even think of this.